# php mysql: Count number of elements that are not present in another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this kind of table right now

```
table a
==============
pid |   block
--------------
1   |   1
2   |   1
3   |   2
4   |   3
5   |   2
6   |   3
--------------

table b
==============
cid |   pid
--------------
1   |   1
2   |   3
3   |   5
--------------

output (count each block who no exist on table b)
===================
block   |   total
-------------------
1       |   1 <--- because on table b exist 1 from 2
2       |   0 <--- because on table b exist 2 from 2
3       |   2 <--- because on table b not exist
-------------------
```

So basically I need to count how many blocks are not present in table b  but are present in table a and sort it based on the block name, is it possible? because i need the result of the count to display as chart

Comment: why block id **1** is having **count 1**, can you please explain in detail ?

Comment: You see on table a block 1 exist 2 time, on pid 1 and pid 2, meanwhile on table b, block 1 only added 1 time which is pid 1

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.block
, 2 - count(distinct b.cid) 
from a
left join b on a.pid = b.pid
group by 1
```

Comment: sorry @holgrich I cancel the accepted answer because I got result not correct when for example I add another data on table a, for example pid 8 with value 3, the result of 3 still 2 it suppose to be 3, here the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367f69/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL:

```
select outera.block , count(outera.block)- (select count(b.pid) from a left join b on a.pid=b.pid  where a.block=outera.block
 group by a.block) as acount  
from a as outera group by outera.block;
```

Please let me know if its working or not.
Thanks.